# leaflet map: update marker using navigator.geolocation.watchPosition?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, leaflet

I'm trying to use a [leaflet map](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) to show the current position of the user on the map. Something like a live GPS tracking.

This is my current code:

```
  var watchID;
         var geoLoc;

         function showLocation(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
         }

         function errorHandler(err) {
            if(err.code == 1) {
               alert("Error: Access is denied!");
            }

            else if( err.code == 2) {
               alert("Error: Position is unavailable!");
            }
         }

         function getLocationUpdate(){
            if(navigator.geolocation){
               // timeout at 60000 milliseconds (60 seconds)
               var options = {timeout:60000};
               geoLoc = navigator.geolocation;
               watchID = geoLoc.watchPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, options);
                var map = L.map('map_2385853')

    googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
}).addTo(map);

      /*L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
      maxZoom: 18
      }).addTo(map);*/

      map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});
      function onLocationFound(e) {
        var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
        L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();
        L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
      }
      map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);




            }

            else{
               alert("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
            }
         }




getLocationUpdate();
```

This code only adds the marker once and doesn't do anything else with it (doesn't remove or add another) when the user's location changes.

I tried the above code on my mobile device and I can confirm that the marker only gets added once and stays there.

Could someone please advise on this?

**HERE IS A WORKING FIDDLE:**

https://jsfiddle.net/31ws6z37/

EDIT:

This is what i have so far. but I get the following error:

**ERROR:**

```
TypeError: map.removeLayer(...).bindPopup is not a function


map.removeLayer(marker)
```

**CODE:**

```
         function initializeMapAndLocator(){

                var map = L.map('map_2385853');


    googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
}).addTo(map);



           map.locate({setView: true, 
                       maxZoom: 16, 
                       watch:true, 
                       timeout: 60000
                      });

      function onLocationFound(e) {
        var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
        //L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
        marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, {draggable:true})
        map.addLayer(marker)
        map.removeLayer(marker)
            .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();
        L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
      }
      map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);



         }

initializeMapAndLocator();
```

Comment: Did you tried to add the marker in the geoLoc.watchPosition() callback ?

Comment: @Manuel, that is what I am doing in my code! hence it gets added once but the location of marker doesn't get updated!

Comment: I only see that you call "showLocation"

Comment: ans please add a fiddle that would make it easier

Comment: @Manuel, I have added a fiddle to my question. https://jsfiddle.net/31ws6z37/

Comment: Thank you I will have a look today or tomorrow !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm it's not clear for me why you are using, two same methods for the same approach. You are using [`Geolocation.watchPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) and [`map.locate()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-locate), which do fundamentally the same things. In this snippet [`Geolocation.watchPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) has no purpose, it only call's `showLocation(position)`, which just initialize two variables. The second method you are using is [`map.locate()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-locate), what should be your function of choice. Here you are doing right to add your marker, but regarding to the [docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-watch) you have to set the `watch` option to `true` using `map.locate()` . You are going better to remove the [`Geolocation.watchPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) and to it simply with [`map.locate()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-locate):

```
function initializeMapAndLocator(){

var map = L.map('map_2385853')

googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
    }).addTo(map);



map.locate({setView: true, 
             maxZoom: 16, 
             watch:true
           });

function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();
    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
}

map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

}


initializeMapAndLocator();
```

Here goes a [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/31ws6z37/1/) triggering *locate* and adding a marker with circle.

Comment: Thank Manuel. Although, i am a bit confused. so basically, by running your code with watch: true, the map acts as a live GPS and it will update the marker as the device's lat/long changes?

Comment: Yes is that what you wanted to do ?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I was trying to do. :)... I didn't know Leaflet provides that out of the box (sort of)....

Comment: ahh ok thats fine that i could help you :) If you have further questions don't fear to ask !

Comment: I just tested it on my device and it seems to work but it doesn't remove the 'previous' marker. it keeps adding the new ones as the new Location (lat/long) gets updated. so basically, the map ends up with so many markers.. any suggestion on that?

Comment: Yes.. Just remove the previous marker and circle befor the new gets created. Initialize the marker over a variable (marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, {draggable:true} map.addLayer(marker);) and then you could do map.removeLayer(marker)

Comment: I've added the new code to my question but I get an error!

Comment: I think that should be posted in a new post, because your last question was answered and this is a new issue. So pls remove the "edit" above und post you issue in a new qustionpost

Comment: Sure, Thanks Manuel. I will post a new one.

Comment: sry but theres now no time for me ! i will have a look tomorror or evening

Comment: Hi, sorry for bringing this question up, I have the same problem of @Jackson ... did you find a way to delete the previous markers?

Comment: Save the previous marker in a container outside of onLocationFound(e). And inside the onLocationFound() function ask for the items and remove the markers you do not want to show. So you can clear the container to only show the last position or show the last nth position by removing only the last nth markers.