# leaflet place marker whenever position changes with watchposition?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, leaflet

In my Ionic app I would like to place a marker in the user position and change its position whenever the one of the user changes.
Is it possible to do that?
I thought I could do something like this:

```
        let marker1;
        let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
        watch.subscribe((data)=>{
          var lat = data.coords.latitude
          var lon =  data.coords.longitude
          let latlng = {lat: lat, lng: lon}
          marker1 = L.marker(latlng)
          let content1 = `<b>You are here</b>`;
            marker1.bindPopup(content1) 
            marker1.addTo(this.map)

        }, error => {

        })
```

but I'm wondering if will be drawn on the map a series of markers for the different positions, instead of "overriding" the previous one.
I currently haven't tried it 'cause I can't simulate the change of position, but I was wondering if this is the right way to do that or I'm going completely wrong.

Comment: You should be able to test location changes in chromes sensor emulation. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/device-input-and-sensors

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime

Comment: Also, this seems to be spot on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40437622/814031